# Userform and Selecting Cell values

Tags: excel, vba

Just playing around with userform. Pretty new to using them . Created a pretty simple userform that find me the percentage change between two values that I enter. (see image below). I'm just interested in going one step further, I want to know how to enter the values based on excel cells that I select. So in this example, if I select K6, the value 15 enters in current year and if I subsequently click on K8, the value 10 enters in base year). Hope that makes sense, let me know if that is possible. Thanks.

current code....

```
TextBox3_Change()
TextBox3.Value = Format((Val(TextBox1.Value) - Val(TextBox2.Value)) / Val(TextBox2.Value), "#0.00%")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than clicking, why not load the values in those textboxes in the `UserForm_Initialize()` event? Something like

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    TextBox1.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K6").Value2
End Sub
```

If you really want to select a cell (*after the userform is shown*) and then populate the textboxes, then yes that is also possible. Here is an example

For demonstration purpose, I am going to populate 1 textbox. Let's say our userform looks like this. Note, I added a `CommandButton1` next to the textbox. I changed the caption to `...`. We will use `Application.InputBox` with `Type:=8` so that user can select a range.

[image]

Next paste this code in the userform code area

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
    '~~> Prompt user to select range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select the range", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    '~~> Check if the user selected a range
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Check if the range is single cell or not
        If rng.Columns.Count > 1 Or rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then
            MsgBox "Select single cell"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        TextBox1.Text = rng.Value2
    End If
End Sub
```

**Demonstration**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a built-in functionality for userforms (unlock the create a graph dialogue box).

One option would be to have the user start by selecting two cells, and then your code runs and calculates the percentage change in those two cells selected and returns the answer in a pop-up. Another option would be to have the userform automatically populate from preselected cells in your workbook (example below).

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    
    Dim ActiveR As Long
        ActiveR = ActiveCell.Row
     
    TextBox1.Value = Cells(ActiveR, 1).Value
    TextBox2.Value = Cells(ActiveR, 2).Value
    TextBox3.Value = Cells(ActiveR, 3).Value
    TextBox4.Value = Cells(ActiveR, 4).Value
End Sub
```